# What is the difference between a regular expression quoted by ` and "?

Tags: regex, go

Why  the `C:\\\\` (quoted by `)  [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp)  does not match `"C:\\"` and `"C:\\\\"` do ?

```
r, err := regexp.Compile(`C:\\\\`) // Not match
r, err := regexp.Compile("C:\\\\")  // Matches
if r.MatchString("Working on drive C:\\") == true {
    fmt.Printf("Matches.") 
} else {
    fmt.Printf("No match.")
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us which language is it ?

Comment: @Theox The question is properly tagged.

Comment: @hvd Ah, indeed, it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Escape sequences in raw string literal (quoted by quotes) are not interpreted.

```
`C:\\\\`
```

is equivalent to:

```
"C:\\\\\\\\"
```

See [The Go Programming Language Specification - String literals](http://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals).

Comment: Yeah, `raw string literal`, this is what I'm missing , I should send a pull request to address [this issue](https://github.com/StefanSchroeder/Golang-Regex-Tutorial/issues/6) in the [Golang-Regex-Tutorial](https://github.com/StefanSchroeder/Golang-Regex-Tutorial), thanks a lot @falsetru for the quick concise answer.